# Swagger is hanging

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I have hosted ASP.NET web api on IIS Express, whenever I try to click on endpoint, it is hanging. Why?
how to overcome it
When I am expanding an endpoint, swagger UI rendering request body and response body very slow. That causing too much delay in Swagger UI

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question lacks on details and [mre]. Have you tried executing requests via postman or something similar?